# Newmann-Penrose Spin coefficients for Schwarzschild metric

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

I need to use the N-P formalism to apply in my work so I'm trying first to apply in a simple case to understand better. So in this article (https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.02764) which I'm using, they present a null tetrad for the Schwarzschild metric in pg.14 (with accordance with the Chandrasekhar tetrad in "mathematical theory of black holes pg.134-135):
$${e_{(A)}}^\mu=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\begin{bmatrix}
1/X & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & -X & 0 & 0 \\
0&0&1/r&\frac{i}{rsin\theta}\\
0&0&1/r&-\frac{i}{rsin\theta}
\end{bmatrix},\;\;A=1,2,3,4;\;\;\mu=t,r,\phi,\theta;\;\;X=1-\frac{2M}{r}$$
For calculating the spin coefficient (one of them for example): $$\mu=\gamma_{243}=\frac{1}{2}\big(C_{243}+C_{432}-C_{324}\big);\;\;\;{C^D}_{AB}=({e^D}_{\alpha,\beta}-{e^D}_{\beta,\alpha}){e_A}^\alpha {e_B}^\beta$$
$$C_{ABC}=\eta_{AD}{C^D}_{BA},\;\;\;{A}\;,_\mu\equiv\partial_\mu A.$$
Then I found the inverse needed above:
$${e^{(A)}}_\mu=\frac{\sqrt2}{2}\begin{bmatrix}
X & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & -1/X & 0 & 0 \\
0 &  0 & r & -irsin\theta\\
0 &  0 & r &  irsin\theta
\end{bmatrix}.$$
Now when I go for the calculation, I just don't get to the mentionated results: $\mu=-\frac{X}{\sqrt2r}$.

The books change index meaning troughtout the texts and I am very confused. In Chandrasekhar pg.81 there is a tetrad and the inverse and there I can reproduce the results, I just don't know why in the other case I'm getting wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Found the right procedure:
Instead of using the tetrad field ${e_a}^\mu$ we should use the field ${\lambda_a}^\mu={e_a}^\mu$ and the field ${\lambda^a}_\mu=g_{\mu\nu}\xi^{ab}{\lambda_b}^\nu$ where:
$$\xi^{ab}=\begin{bmatrix}
0&1&0&0\\
1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&-1\\0&0&-1&0\\
\end{bmatrix}$$
this is because, a null tetrad won't obey the usuall relations between $g_{\mu\nu}\leftrightarrow \eta_{ab}$.
Further:$${C^D}_{BC}=({\lambda^D}_{\mu,\nu}-{\lambda^D}_{\nu,\mu}){\lambda_B}^\mu{\lambda_C}^\nu.$$
This gives us:
${\lambda^a}_\mu=g_{\mu\nu}\xi^{ab}{\lambda_b}^\nu$ where:
$${\lambda^a}_\mu=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\begin{bmatrix}
X&1&0&0\\
1&-1/X&0&0\\0&0&r&-irsin\theta\\0&0&r&irsin\theta\\
\end{bmatrix},$$
Now $\gamma_{243}=-\frac{1}{2}(\xi_{2D}{C^D}_{43}+\xi_{4D}{C^D}_{32}-\xi_{3D}{C^D}_{24})=\frac{-X}{\sqrt 2r}$ , indeed.